How to get the first half of entries per group?
I want to get the first 50% of the time of the data per x.
For example,
the dataset is like this:
x Year

a 2000
a 2001
b 2002
b 2003
b 2004
b 2005
c 2010
c 2020

If a x appeared in Year 2000 & 2001, I want the first 50% of the time of a (i.e. Year 2000) only.
I want to do some subsample, but I do not have any ideas.
The output should be:
a 2000
b 2002
b 2003
c 2010


library(dplyr)

df |>
  slice_min(Year, by = x, prop = 0.50)
#   x Year
# 1 a 2000
# 2 b 2002
# 3 b 2003
# 4 c 2010


with base R, you can use subset + ave
> subset(df, as.logical(ave(x, x, FUN = \(u) seq_along(u) <= length(u) / 2)))
  x Year
1 a 2000
3 b 2002
4 b 2003
7 c 2010


library(dplyr)
your_data |>
  filter(row_number() <= ceiling(n() / 2), .by = x)

This will keep the first 50% of rows, rounded up, for each value of x. If your data isn't already sorted by year, stick an arrange(Year) in first.

Or
> tapply(df0, df0$x, \(x) x[seq(floor(nrow(x) / 2L)), ]) |> 
+   array2DF() |> _[-1L] |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
  x Year
1 a 2000
2 b 2002
3 b 2003
4 c 2010


Using split and head on half a table.
> split(d, ~x) |> Map(head, x=_, table(d$x)/2) |> do.call(what='rbind')
    x Year
a   a 2000
b.3 b 2002
b.4 b 2003
c   c 2010


Data:
> dput(d)
structure(list(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
    Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2010L, 
    2020L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

